# Beamer vs. \xdef vs. \underline

Tags: beamer

I am reporting here an issue that (in a way) has been discovered by the user Blitz of another LaTeX forum [here](https://texwelt.de/wissen/antwort_link/22034/).

Consider the MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{What's going on here?}
\xdef\mytext{\underline{duck}}
\underline{underline is not the problem}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

On my TeXLive 2017 distribution, it throws the error

```
! Use of \beamer@@frametitle doesn't match its definition.
\new@ifnextchar ...served@d = #1\def \reserved@a {
                                                  #2}\def \reserved@b {#3}\f...
l.7 \end{frame}
```

If I replace `\xdef` by `\def`, no error occurs, and when I do not use `\underline` but nothing or `\textbf`, say, everything goes well. After some amount of playing, my impression is that the error appears if `\xdef` and `\underline` are used simultaneously.

**QUESTION**: Why is that and how can it be fixed?

Comment: My general rule of thumb: do definitions outside of frames. If `\xdef\mytext{\underline{duck}}` is moved to the preamble it seems to work fine.

Comment: @samcarter Did you mean "no definitions *inside* frames"? And sometimes one has to do definitions inside frames, or at least things get much simpler that way.

Comment: Yes, no definitions inside frames. Sometimes it works, but it can cause many funny errors - one of which you found.

Comment: I just had a look at the answer you linked to. Can't you simply use the if case inside the node? `\node[right=2cm of pointer\X.one east,murmel] (murmel\X) {
\ifnum\X=4
MSVCRTexhandler
\else
Exception\underline{~~}handler\X ()
\fi 
};`

Comment: `\xdef` isn't a latex command....

Comment: @marmot You could also avoid the underline hack with `\textunderscore`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\underline` in beamer is a fragile command and any such command will give more or less arbitrary errors in `\edef` or `\xdef` or any other moving argument.

It isn't clear why `\xdef` is being used at all, but you can make `\underline` safe in the `\xdef` with `\noexpand`

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{What's going on here?}
\xdef\mytext{\noexpand\underline{duck}}
\underline{underline is not the problem}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```